# How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site

Tags: discussion, site-tools

Many newcomers to this site have code that they entered into their notebooks using one of tje *Mathematica* palettes, e.g.,  Basic Math Assistant. They are delighted with mathematical look of their code, but when they copy such code from their notebook and paste into our editor, they often get a mess they don't know how to deal with. So they just leave the mess or they resort to making a PNG image of their code and posting that.

When they are chided by a community member for posting their code in a bad format, they are often given the advice to copy the code as plain text. My experience is that such advice is not optimal. What would constitute better advice?

Comment: I posted this because I think people might want to give a link to it when making a comment to newcomers about better formatting.

Comment: I added the [tag:site-tools] tag because I thought new users who are directed here would like to see other tools that have been developed to make the site easier to use.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is the way I do it when I have fancy standard form code I want post on *Mathematica*.SE

**Step-by-step**

1. Make a copy of the cell containing the code to be posted
2. Convert the copied cell to **raw input form**

   Choose Convert To > Raw InputForm from the Cell menu or from the contextual (right mouse clidk) menu
3. Select the code and do a normal copy (do not use Copy As)
4. Paste form the clipboard in the *Mathematica*.SE editor pane
5. Delete the raw input form cell from the notebook.

**How it looks in a notebook**

[image: raw-input]

#### Update

This is aimed at newcomers. After you have pasted your code into an editor input pane, you are not done. The code must be block indented by a minimum of four spaces for the editor to recognize that it is code.

Here is some properly indented code without a block indent. It looks terrible because it is displayed without its line breaks and with all the leading indents are compressed to one space.

With[{n = 524},
  xpts = Table[{i h, x[i]}, {i, 0, n}];
  ypts = Table[{i h, y[i]}, {i, 0, n}];]

After carrying out the simple instructions given below, it looks good.

```
With[{n = 524},
  xpts = Table[{i h, x[i]}, {i, 0, n}];
  ypts = Table[{i h, y[i]}, {i, 0, n}];]
```

One way to make a block indent is to use the { } tool from the editor tool bar

1. Select the text you want to block indent
2. Click on the { } icon in the tool bar at the top of the editor input pane

The keyboard shortcut for clicking on the { } tool is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

#### 2nd update

Response to xzczd's comment

The cells produced are quite different.

InputForm

```
Cell[BoxData[
  RowBox[{"Sum", "[", 
    RowBox[{
      RowBox[{
        RowBox[{"Log", "[", "i", "]"}], "/", 
        RowBox[{"i", "^", "2"}]}], ",", " ", 
      RowBox[{"{", 
        RowBox[{"i", ",", " ", "1", ",", " ", "Infinity"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]], "Input",
  FormatType->"InputForm"]
```

Raw InputForm

```
Cell["Sum[Log[i]/i^2, {i, 1, Infinity}]", "Input"]
```

InputForm allows code coloring and other code editor formatting, but Raw InputForm is cleaner and to my mind better for copy and paste.

Comment: How does it handle Greek characters?

Comment: @bbgodfrey. Most are not affected, but π is converted to `Pi`.

Comment: Er… what's the difference between _raw input form_ and _input form_? BTW I always use Ctrl+Shift+I (this is the shortcut for _input form_, right?) to convert the mess and I think I never see this fails.

Comment: Time to Accept this answer, don't you think?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Really? Is their any significance to accepting one's own answer in Meta?

Comment: Not a great deal I suppose, but it *does* show up as having an Accepted answer in the questions list, and I find that beneficial.   No other methods were posted and this one is popular, so I think we can reasonably conclude that this is the "canonical way" and therefore Accept seems appropriate.

Comment: To give a complete protocol for newbies, you might add that clicking the `{}` button (or Control-K) will format the code.

Comment: @MichaelE2. I think that's a good idea. Will update my answer soon -- too busy right now to do it immediately.

Comment: @m_goldberg Steps 1 thru 5 do not work for me. All the greek letters are written out (e.g., \\[Theta]). I am on Mathematica 10.1 and using Internet Explorer 11. Do you have any tips on a work-a-round?

Comment: @JackLaVigne. That's really a different problem from the one I address here. You will find a solution for it in [this meta-post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/3066)

Comment: Response to **2nd update**: though codes in _raw input form_ and _input form_ are different inside the notebook, I think they result in the same text when being copy and paste to somewhere outside of notebook e.g. this site?

Comment: @xzczd. Sorry, but that is not so.

Comment: Show me an example :) ?