# How to post Mathematica code in StackExchange

Tags: discussion

How do I post *Mathematica* code in StackExchange properly? I read some instructions that told me I should copy the  *Mathematica* code from the  *Mathematica* notebook with Copy as >  Plain text or Copy as >  Input text, paste into the SE code editor pane, and put it between \$ \$,

When I did this I still did not get well-formated equations. For example, I got:

`$ eq1[zz_, \[Beta]_] := 2*Subscript[\[Lambda], 1]*v1[\[Beta]]^2 $`

So what did I miss?

Actually I still haven't found an answer. I followed the instruction in
[How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site)

I did the following for a *Mathematica* cell that I wanted to post *Mathematica*.SE site. I convert the contents of the cell to Raw InputForm and then pasted intp SE editor between `\$ $`, like

`$ eq1[zz_, \[Beta]_] := 2*Subscript[\[Lambda], 1]*v1[\[Beta]]^2 + 2*Subscript[\[Lambda], 2]*v2[\[Beta]]^2 $`

Nothing, so I also tried to put between `{ }`, like

`{eq1[zz_, \[Beta]_] := 2*Subscript[\[Lambda], 1]*v1[\[Beta]]^2 + 2*Subscript[\[Lambda], 2]*v2[\[Beta]]^2 }`

So I'm afraid I didn't understand the instructions in the referred post.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Let me try here, I convert the equation to : Raw InputForm, then past here between \$ $:   $eq1[zz_, \[Beta]_] := 2*Subscript[\[Lambda], 1]*v1[\[Beta]]^2 + 4*Subscript[\[Lambda], 2]*v2[\[Beta]]^2} $                    or \{}                                   {eq1[zz_, \[Beta]_] := 2*Subscript[\[Lambda], 1]*v1[\[Beta]]^2 + 4*Subscript[\[Lambda], 2]*v2[\[Beta]]^2}

Comment: Please look at my question, because I added.

Comment: @S.S. I don't know where you saw you should the enclose code you copy from a notebook in `\$ \$`, but that is wrong and don't do it.

Comment: Unless the code has special symbols or formatting, you can just copy it from your notebook and paste it into SE.  If it is just a short piece of code, you can include it in a line of text by surrounding it by backquotes, as in `x + y`.  However, it is a longer piece of code or you wish it to stand alone on a line, paste it into a blank line, highlight it, and click the {} symbol about the SE code editor box.  (Equivalently, separate it from text by a blank line and indent it four spaces.)  In this case, do not surround it by backquotes. Do not surround it by dollar signs unless you want LaTex.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have code with complex formatting, convert it to input form by using the Mathematica `InputForm` command, and then copy and paste the result. This leaves Greek letters to format properly.  For many web viewers, use [Halirutan's editor](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor).  See also [my earlier question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/installing-halirutans-script-in-internet-explorer-11).

Comment: Thanx for the replies.