# System keeps rejecting latex in questions

Tags: discussion

In my last two questions, whenever I tried pasting mathjax, the system would tell me that I am trying to paste code without code-syntax, and that I should please change that. For example,

I cannot post this in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/149429/edit):

$$ H(s) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } s < n_0 \
e^{\lambda (s - n_1)} & \text{ if } n_0 \leq s \leq n_1 \
1 & \text{ if } s > n_1 \end{cases}$$

I posted it with the code tags, and A golden user could then edit the tags out on my behalf. Even now that the latex is edited into the question, I cannot save changes myself anymore (even if I do no changes, because it keeps telling me that

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I wonder whether low rep users are not supposed to use mathjax on this site, or whether this is a legitimate bug?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the system, i.e., not any program Stack Exchange is running, that is removing your mathjax -- it's the Mathematica.SE members who are editing your posts who are removing it.

In the case of your most recent question, I substituted an image of the code for the mathjax because I thought the image was easier to read. But it wasn't the best choice. Better would have been to insert the Mathematica expression as raw input. I have edited the question again, making that insertion.

Converting Mathematica code, whether taken from input cells or output cells is almost never a good idea. Expressions that Mathematica has displayed with fancy formatting should be converted to input form or raw input form.

See [this question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) for more info on formatting questions.

Comment: I have rewritten the question with a more extreme example