# Why do I sometimes get boxes when I try to paste an equation?

Tags: support

I was just trying to ask a question but when I started to paste the equations I got

```
disp = {u[r, z], w[r, z]};
ddisp = {
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r, z], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r, z], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r, z], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r, z]};
```

Normally I just get a simple equation that is clear to see. The start of this paste is like that. However, it then goes into endless boxes. Have I done something wrong? How do I avoid this? How can I tell if I am about to paste Boxes rather than simple input?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be more common for me in version 12 - copying a control-equals box for instance.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/

Comment: As @ CarlLange pointed out, this seems to be a *new* problem since Mathematica 12, and *"Copy as Plain Text"* doesn't seem to be a real solution, if the *"the code for derivatives is not valid input"*, as pointed out by @ MichaelE2, so I don't think that this question is settled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Copy As > PlainText** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
disp = {u[r, z], w[r, z]};
ddisp = {
(u^(1,0))[r, z], 
(u^(0,1))[r, z], 
(w^(1,0))[r, z], 
(w^(0,1))[r, z]};
```

Comment: You probably know this, but one drawback is that the code for derivatives is not valid input.